# When did the $L^p$ start being mentioned and who proved that $L^p$ spaces are complete?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, math-history

I know the theorem that assures this is called "Riesz-Fischer Theorem" but doing a bit of research I found out that Riesz and Fischer proved simultaneously that $L^2$ is complete without mentioning any concept of "complete" nor "$L^2$".

So my question is: Who did the proof that $L^p$ is complete for $p\neq 2$ and when did these spaces start being relevant? Any hep or reference would help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space), $L^p$ spaces for general $p$ were introduced in 1910 by Riesz in the paper

> *Riesz, F.*, [**Untersuchungen über Systeme integrierbarer Funktionen.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01457637), Math. Ann. 69, 449-497 (1910). [ZBL41.0383.01](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:41.0383.01).

which is freely available online at http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002263491.
My German is not very good, but it appears to me that this paper considers $L^p$ spaces for all $1<p<\infty$, and on page 468, it states and proves the completeness of $L^p$ for all such $p$ and calls this result a generalization of a theorem of Fischer (citing Fischer's paper which proved the completeness of $L^2$).

Comment: I was just about to post the same and agree completely (and my German is native).

Comment: Here is a non-paywall link: http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002263491